# How to download only a part of an HTML document using Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup, web-crawler

I try to crawl Data from webpages just like amazon, but I'm only interested in the price of the products. When I try to crawl a lot of data it needs way too much time to download the full HTML document. So I desire to download only the part, where the Price stands (like the first 300kb), of the HTML document. It would be even better to download only a part in the middle of HTML document if this is possible, but it would be enough to have a solution on how to only download a specific number of bytes. I am using Jsoup to crawl data. It would be great if someone is able and willing to help me :)

Comment: downloading only part of an html page will leave you with a corrupted file, and a lot of dangling tags, even tags chopped in half. most any dom parser is going to reject that outright.

Comment: You can't request only part of a file. You can inspect the received bytes to check if the information is there, then close the connection if it is. But you won't be able to parse it to HTML (because the document is incomplete), and you'll have to work around the fact that the bytes do not arrive in order.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask Amazon if they don't have a nice webservice that you can use to do this with their actual permission.

Comment: You definitely can't download the "middle" of a file (byte range requests are only really supported for video/audio files). You could open a URL as a stream like this: `URL url= new URL("http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Book/dp/059035342X"); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));` but then you still have to parse the stream manually, which is going to be next to impossible, and do it before the file downloads anyway. Amazon have [various APIs](https://developer.amazon.com/); see if one of them helps.

Comment: What is the problem with jsoup?

Comment: @cy3er that's true, jsoup could probably parse a stream from a URL, in theory.